# Solr indexing time vs performance

Tags: solr

I am new to Solr and using in my project where i have large number of products with a number of properties. So the indexing takes a whole lot of time. But if i don't index all the properties then the results will have to be populated via a separate db hit. But that kind of loses the significance of the Solr, doesn't it? Since we are hitting db anyways, doesn't that make the query slower? Kindly guide whats the right approach. Indexing all properties or getting the remaining properties from db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An hybrid choice is not necessarily the evil. Basically that choice depends on what kind of search features and services you want to offer to your users. For instance

- if you want to facet over a "category" field you need to put that field on Solr
- if you want to have some data in real time (e.g. price) I would go with the database

In general you should experiment and try because all your thoughts make sense but, my suggestion, don't optimize things in advance. Write down your (search and view) requirements and on top of that try to get a good compromise between the two extremes (only solr / only database)

Comment: thanks a ton,,, this is the approach i was thinking. i could index the values needed for searching.... and then load the values from the db....